# cloud functions firebase v9 runTransaction

Tags: node.js, firebase, transactions, google-cloud-functions

this is my cloud function:

```
const { getFirestore, runTransaction, FieldValue } = require('firebase-admin/firestore')

exports.purchasesStatistics = functions.firestore
    .document('transactions/{purchaseId}')
    .onUpdate((snap, context ) => {
      if (snap.before.data().status === 'RECEIVED') {
        return '0'
      }
      let purchasePaid = snap.after.data().status === 'RECEIVED' ? true : false
      if (purchasePaid === false) {
        return '0'
      }
      let allPurchase = snap.after.data()
      functions.logger.log('allPurchase', allPurchase)
      let ref = getFirestore().collection('statistics').doc('checkout')
      return runTransaction(ref, (transaction) => {
        return transaction.get(ref).then((doc) => {
          functions.logger.log('documento atualizado:', doc.data())
          return '0'
        })
      })
    })
```

Buy, it's returning "runTransaction is not a function". What i'm doing wrong ? Didn't find proper way to use runTransaction on firebase v9

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using the [admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#node.js_1) for NodeJS. This SDK is initialized differently from the Web SDK V9 and the way you use the functions is also different. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) is a detailed guide on how to initialize the admin SDK from scratch. After trying to add or import the `runTransaction()` function as your sample code, I also received the same error message. I followed the get [started guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#node.js_1) in addition to the documentation [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#node.js) to properly use this function, by using it from the firestore object that is created:

```
const { initializeApp, applicationDefault, cert } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const { getFirestore } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');
const serviceAccount = require('/path-to-service-account'); //Path to your service account, depends on implementation

initializeApp({
    credential: cert(serviceAccount)
});

const fireDB = getFirestore();
fireDB.runTransaction(); //Use the relevant args
```

This additional [page](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore_.html#runTransaction) contains a different example for using transactions.